# Is there a way to use own package's data (internal or external) as a default S4 class slot?

Tags: r, r-package, r-s4

Is there a way to use my own package's data (internal or external) as a default S4 class slot?

If I create some package data:

```
my_pkg_data <- sample(100)

usethis::use_data(my_pkg_data, internal=FALSE)
```

I can make functions taking the data as a default parameter:

```
#' Title
#'
#' @param x foo
#'
#' @return nout
#' @export
#'
foo <- function(x = test::my_pkg_data) {

  print(x)

}

#run
foo() 
   [1]  407  184   13  994  933  322  214  784  502  396  903 ....
```

However, if creating S4 classes I get an error running devtools::check():

```
#' Title
#'
#' @slot some_slot ...
#' @return a s4class object
#' @export
#'
s4class <- setClass(
  Class = "s4class",
  slots = list(
    some_slot = "ANY"
  ),
  prototype = list(
    some_slot = test::my_pkg_data
  )
)
```

devtools::check()

```
* installing *source* package ‘test’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error : 'my_pkg_data' is not an exported object from 'namespace:test'
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘test’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘test’
* removing ‘/private/var/folders/62/n2yrhw752hn73nlbzp0r0_rr0000gq/T/RtmpvHbEA2/file36f3594c2270/test.Rcheck/test’

1 error ✖ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
Package: test
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person("First", "Last", , "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: MIT + file LICENSE
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Depends: 
    R (>= 2.10)
LazyData: true
```

NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(foo)
export(s4class)
exportClasses(s4class)
```

data.R file:

```
#' @title my data
#' @name my_pkg_data
"my_pkg_data"
```

Is this possible? Do I have to do this in an S4 initialise function instead? What's the reason behind this?

for example this works:

```
setMethod(
  f = "initialize",
  signature = "s4class",
  definition = function(.Object, some_slot=test::my_pkg_data) {
    .Object@some_slot <- some_slot
    validObject(.Object)
    return(.Object)
  }
)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I never use S4 so I don’t know a lot of it but the issue is probably that the S4 class definition is evaluated at installation time, before the data is loaded. Whereas in the function definition the parameter default is evaluated *inside the function, when the function is called*, which happens *after* the package has been fully loaded (including making the data available). To avoid the S4 issue you could create the S4 class in the package’s `.onLoad` function, but this is probably a bad idea for reasons relating to S4. But maybe you can fill the slot defaults of an existing class in `onLoad`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setClass` is called at install time and almost always evaluates its `prototype` argument, hence the error.  You'd encounter a similar error at install time if under the definition of `foo` you tried to evaluate a call such as `foo()`.

In your situation, I would simply define a method for `initialize`:

```r
> tools::assertError(Matrix::USCounties) # an error, as not lazy-loaded
> setClass("zzz", slots = c(x = "ANY"))
> setMethod("initialize", "zzz",
+           function(.Object, ...) {
+               .Object <- callNextMethod(.Object, ...)
+               if (all(...names() != "x")) {
+                   data(USCounties, package = "Matrix", envir = environment())
+                   .Object@x <- USCounties
+               }
+               .Object
+           })
> z1 <- new("zzz")
> data(USCounties, package = "Matrix")
> stopifnot(identical(z1, new("zzz", x = USCounties)))
```